# Как установить сетевой принтер HP laser jet cp1025 на ubuntu 10.04

Tags: установка, x11, принтер

Подскажите! Принтер установлен на стационар с `Windows xp`, ubantu на нетбуке, по сети нетбук его видит, устанавливает драйвера, печатать не печатает.ОШИБКА:

> При обработке документа test page задание 78 возникла проблема.

`hpcups v3.12.6` установлен. Спасибо!

Comment: вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, думаю, в авторизации.

Проверьте: `smbclient -L ПринтерХост`.

Если печатаете через `cups`, добавьте в `/etc/cups/printer.conf:`

```
 DeviceURI smb://User:Password@ПринтерХост/ИмяПринтера
```

Answer (score 0):

в файле printers.conf вроде все есть

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.4.3# Written by cupsd# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING<DefaultPrinter HP-LaserJet-Cp-1025>Info HP LaserJet Cp 1025Location qpostasMakeModel HP LaserJet Cp 1025, hpcups 3.12.6, requires proprietary pluginDeviceURI smb://10.0.1.7/HPLaserJState IdleStateTime 1343365905Reason hplip.plugin-errorType 36876Filter application/vnd.cups-raw 0 -Filter application/vnd.cups-raster 0 hpcupsAccepting YesShared YesJobSheets none noneQuotaPeriod 0PageLimit 0KLimit 0OpPolicy defaultErrorPolicy retry-job</Printer>
```

Comment: DeviceURI smb://User:Password@ПринтерХост/ИмяПринтераНе хватает Имени пользователя и пароля в Вашем конфиге

Comment: не помогло,может есть еще решения?

Comment: включите расширенный лог для Cups в cups.conf:LogLevel debug2И посмотрите что происходит.